# Changing floating button image size programmatically

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have floating button and image inside. And I need image to change size filling all space inside like here:|

[image]

I tried different scale types but it did't work. I got this result for now.

[image]

Finally I found the solution - maxImageSize. It worked, but now I need to set Fbutton size programmatically and I can't find the way to change maxImageSize in code.

Comment: Hi, same pb here - did you figure it out?

Answer (score -2):

When you set the maxImageSize in the XML, you are changing the normal behavior and icon size of the FAB.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/fab_main"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorBottomAppBarFab"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            app:maxImageSize="56dp"/>
```

The result of this code is : [FAB with image size 56dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVsEv.png)

Later to change it again but programatically, you can use ScaleType to change the icon dimensions.
Here an example in Kotlin:

```
fab_main.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE
```

And then, here is the new result:
[FAB with smaller icon size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35zzc.png)

If you want to change FAB dimensions, may be using one of the following methods can help you: [FAB methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySHEK.png)

I hope this solution can help you.

Comment: The question is how to do "app:maxImageSize" programmatically